# Android: Debugging Android Applications on a Handset

Tags: android

I am trying debug android aplication on real phone (HTC Desire).
I enabled USB debugging on my Android Device.
Then i clicked on debug configuration,set Deployment Target Selection Mode to Manual and i clicked on debug but in Android Device Choiser i can't see my phone.
What can i do please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using eclipse as your IDE. I have to say that I use IDEA, So my experience with debugging could be different.

These are the steps that I have to do:

1- Enable USB Debugging. ( You have already enabled it).

2- Download HTC Sync software for my Computer (MacBook).

3- Close already open emulator and connect the device to my computer.

4- Start debugging session.

I did not get a device chooser dialog also. But to my surprise the phone was chosen over the emulator.I do not know how much you can get from my personal experience, but its worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install drivers for the phone on the host machine. You can probably get the driver from HTC.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to install the drivers for that device on your PC for the debugger to be able to see it. Also set the option in Android to allow install of non market applications. I almost forgot that your project also needs android:debuggable="true". See the link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Answer (score 1):

That varies depending your operative system.

On Mac you should be set to go.

On windows you may have to download USB drivers.

On Linux you may have to change a configuration file.

Read the how-to here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html